# How to get innerHTML of a Table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

```
 HtmlTable baseCalendar = new HtmlTable();
 HtmlTableRow calendarRow=new HtmlTableRow();
 HtmlTableCell calendarCell = new HtmlTableCell();

 for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
       calendarCell = new HtmlTableCell();

       calendarCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(i.ToString()));
       calendarCell.Style.Add("color", "red");
       calendarRow.Cells.Add(calendarCell);

 }



 string resutlt=baseCalendar.innerHtml.Tostring();
```

this line say error:HtmlTable' does not support the InnerHtml property?????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you want the HTML code for the table you created which cannot be achieved by innerHTML those are valid in case of div, here you should rather use `RenderControl` something on these lines

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
baseCalendar.RenderControl(htw)
```

Comment: tanks very very very much . this is ok!!1

Comment: to get the string:      
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                baseCalendar.RenderControl(htw);

Comment: how can i add the HTML tages in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.innerhtml%28VS.80%29.aspx

Do not read from or assign a value to this property. Otherwise, a System.NotSupportedException exception is thrown. This property is inherited from the HtmlContainerControl class and is not applicable to the HtmlTable class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use manually write a Table instead of using HtmlTable

```
 string str = "<table>";
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    str += "<tr><td style='color:red'>" + i.ToString() + "</td></tr>";
                }
                str += "</table>";
                mainDiv.InnerHtml = str;
```

And in ASPX page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="mainDiv">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

A HtmlTable does have the InnerHtml property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.aspx

You are missing a caps:

```
string resutlt=baseCalendar.innerHtml.Tostring(); // note innerHtml -> InnerHtml
```

However, even though it will compile, you must note that:

> #### Caution
>
> Do not read from or assign a value to this property.
>   Otherwise, a System.NotSupportedException exception is thrown. This
>   property is inherited from the HtmlContainerControl class and is not
>   applicable to the HtmlTable class.