# Getting the InnerHtml of an HTMLTable C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, html-table

This function is returning an HTML table:

```
private HtmlTable ConvertToHtml(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            var htmlTable = new HtmlTable();
            if (dataTable == null) return htmlTable; //null reference, empty table

            HtmlTableRow htmlRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            htmlTable.Rows.Add(htmlRow);

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                htmlRow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = column.ColumnName });

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                htmlRow = new HtmlTableRow();
                htmlTable.Rows.Add(htmlRow);

                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                    htmlRow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = row[column].ToString() });
            }

            return htmlTable;
        }
```

I would like to know how I can get the `innerHTML` of `HtmlTable`.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
        var bodyhtml = ConvertToHtml(r.tblSalesVolume);
        MessageBox.Show(bodyhtml.InnerHtml);
```

but it says that it doesn't have such a property.

How do I get the HTML code for the table?

Comment: Duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789639/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-a-table-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use HtmlTable.RenderControl() method.

Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

HtmlTable.RenderControl(hw);
String HTMLContent = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789639/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-a-table-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: @I__: You would have to write `bodyHtml.RenderControl(hw);`. Bcos that is object you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You've written `InnerText` as the property, you should write `InnerHtml`. And there is no need for `ToString()` as `HtmlTable.InnerHtml` is a string.

See [HtmlTable.InnerHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.innerhtml.aspx)

---

why don't you just create the html instead of using HtmlTable? instead of TableRow you just use  before the "cell"-loop and  after the "cell"-loop. and when you write a cell you just write ´value´.´There really isn't any reason to use HtmlTable to create the table html string.

---

```
private string ConvertToHtml(DataTable dataTable)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<table>");

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr>");

        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(column.ColumnName));
        sb.Append("</tr>");

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>");

            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(row[column]));

            sb.Append("</tr>");
        }

    }

    sb.Append("</table>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
  Message="'HtmlTable' does not support the InnerHtml property."

Comment: i dont know if this is relevant but i'm using winforms

Comment: @Simon: The link says "this property is not supported for this control".

Comment: @I__: guess you are referencing "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls: in your WinForms project.

Comment: @Simon: "Do not read from or assign a value to this property. Otherwise, a System.NotSupportedException exception is thrown. This property is inherited from the HtmlContainerControl class and is not applicable to the HtmlTable class."

Comment: @Kash yes i am referning htmlcontrols

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9106/discussion-between-i-and-kash)

Comment: @Kash, Yeah I just noticed. I didn't think to check the usage of the property, as I assumed the OP had just made a typo.

Comment: @I__, why don't you just create the html instead of using `HtmlTable`? instead of `TableRow` you just use `<tr>` before the "cell"-loop and `</tr>` after the "cell"-loop. and when you write a cell you just write ´<td>value</td>´.´There really isn't any reason to use `HtmlTable` to create the table html string

Comment: @SimonBangTerkildsen thank you can you please update your answer with what you are saying

Comment: @I__, I've rewritten your `ConvertToHtml` method so it doesn't use `HtmlTable` and `HtmlTableRow`

Comment: @SimonBangTerkildsen: In this case using StringBuilder, you may have to consider HtmlEncoding for the contents of the cells with special characters like anchors and backslash.

Comment: @|__, I've updated the code, as Kash pointed out, that the cell-values wasn't being encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Leon's answer, using HtmlTable.RenderControl() with OP's code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

var bodyhtml = ConvertToHtml(r.tblSalesVolume);

bodyhtml.RenderControl(hw);
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```